# cant iterate object array in template of component in typescript angular2

Tags: angular, typescript2.0

I have service which return objects to component, and iterate objects inside template, some of the properties might be null and breaks the js how can I prevent this to happen ?

template:

```
<table id="simple-table" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
 <caption>Table of artists</caption>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>id</th>
            <th>name</th>
            <th>image</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let artist of artists">

            <td>{{artist.id}}</td>
            <td>{{artist.name}}</td>
            <td><img class="img-circle" style="width:100%" src="{{artist.images[0].url}}"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

artist.images[0].url throws "annot read property 'url' of undefined" error since images is null how can I fix in single line with cascade conditions ?

Comment: What does  `console.log(this.artists)` print instead of  `console.log(data)`?

Comment: What does `<div>{{artists | json}}</div>` display?

Comment: @echonax its sam, i set breakpoint in subscription function and check the value of artist property, all objects loaded, nothing suspicious looking  in there

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer nothing, I think something wrong with binding here..

Comment: Can you try adding `private cdRef:ChangeDetectorRef` to constructor parameters and call `this.cdRef.detectChanges()` after `this.artists = ...;`?

Comment: omg my bad is getting service response since I expected as json when I change "data" to "data.artists" it works now. sorry. i can accept answers any of you direct me to find issue thanks

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer can you check the post? my other common issue which I have also here, edited post this should be more helpfull thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can safe-navigation `?.` instead of `.` but not with `[]`.

This should work

```
artists?.images && artist.images[0]?.url
```

or alternatively

```
<table *ngIf="artists.images.length" ...
```